# How to keep a bash script open with wget or curl while executing and piping it to bash

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I'm trying to execute a bin script directly from a remote repository using either `wget` or `curl`.  However when I run `wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/example/typescript/main/bin/init | bash` or `curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/example/typescript/main/bin/init | bash` it immediately closes off the script and exits it.

Inside that script I'm using a `read` command to get user input, but it never ends up reading the input and just exits the script before ever completing it.

How can I use the `wget` or `curl` commands to get the file, pipe it to bash and keep it running and open and fully complete the script before exiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, with `curl`,

```bash
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://raw.githubusercontent.com/example/typescript/main/bin/init | sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Which part exactly is it that keeps open the connection, specifying the https protocol or the tls?

Comment: @MiaMatriarx To be honest, I don't know. I just copied the command used for an other software that has similar setup (you can find it on rustup.rs). If you want more details, I'd suggest reading the man page of `curl`.

Comment: Alright.  I have read the man page and 20 different stackexchanges but I can not find anywhere that tells me exactly what part prevents it from exiting.